# EventCallback vs Action

Tags: c#, blazor

I am working on a Blazor project and some of the grids we are creating can have many columns and/or rows. I had read that lambda functions are "expensive" and read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0#avoid-recreating-delegates-for-many-repeated-elements-or-components) that an `Action` is the way to go.

So using that example I added a property to my `Cell` class as such:

`public Action<MouseEventArgs> Action { get; set; } = (e) => { };`

And then to use this property while setting up the cells I do:

`someRow.FixedCells[0].Action = (e) => { SwapIngredientRows(someRow, false); };`

Prior to this change the Razor code was:

`@onclick="@(() => SwapIngredientRows(row, false))"`

This `SwapIngredientRows` method is `async` and does await 2 calls internally and graphically updates the screen.

Once I changed it to:

`@onclick="cell.Action"`

The actual database is updated but the UI is not updated when calling the **exact same** method.

I am wondering if I could change the `Action` to a `Func` or `EventCallback` or something so it behaves just like the original lambda method I started with?

## Updated with Enhancement

After using the @hank-holterman solution for a while and loving it, I eventually needed to know when the `Control` key was pressed while clicking. The following is the adjusted property:

```
public Func<MouseEventArgs, Task> Action { get; set; }
```

And I use it like:

```
Action = (e) => ProcessClick(e, my, other, properties)
```

Where `e` are the `MouseEventArgs`. If you do not need the `MouseEventArgs` then just do not pass them into your method:

```
Action = (e) => DumbClick(my, other, properties)
```

And the `razor` syntax does not need to change:

```
@onclick="cell.Action"
```

Comment: Not sure if it will solve your issue but you can create an EventCallback like this `EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this, Action);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is this:

> `someRow.FixedCells[0].Action = (e) => { SwapIngredientRows(someRow, false); };`
> This SwapIngredientRows method is async

That means that SwapIngredientRows() is not awaited anymore and effectively it has become an `async void`. That is why your UI does not update.

You can fix it by replacing the `Action` with a `Func<Task>`. The MouseEventArgs can be ignored.

```
public Func<Task> Action { get; set; } = () => Task.CompletedTask;

someRow.FixedCells[0].Action = () => SwapIngredientRows(someRow, false);

@onclick="cell.Action" // the generated code will await the Task
```

No StateHasChanged() required, the onclick event handles it all.

Comment: This is perfect @henk-holterman, turns out I had to do this to not get compiler actions `someRow.FixedCells[0].Action = async () => { await SwapIngredientRows(someRow, false); };`

Comment: Good answer.  You're "caching" the delegate so removing the expensive construction on each call, and triggering the UI Update with `@onclick`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have a new situation where I now need to have the `MouseEventArgs` to come across as well as whatever `Func` I have. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you change a variable (which is used in the UI) from a callback or `Action`, you need to tell that the state has changed, like so:

```cs
StateHasChanged();
```

You need to do this in the callback or `Action` to tell the UI thread that there is an update.

If you are changing the state from another thread, you have to invoke the method, like so:

```cs
InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
```

Answer (score 2):

For some background to this question, the way UI events are handled by a component is governed by it's `IHandleEvent` implementation.

The `ComponentBase` implementation looks like this:

```cs
    Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        var task = callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
        var shouldAwaitTask = task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion &&
            task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

        // After each event, we synchronously re-render (unless !ShouldRender())
        // This just saves the developer the trouble of putting "StateHasChanged();"
        // at the end of every event callback.
        StateHasChanged();

        return shouldAwaitTask ?
            CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(task) :
            Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch // avoiding exception filters for AOT runtime support
        {
            // Ignore exceptions from task cancellations, but don't bother issuing a state change.
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                return;
            }

            throw;
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Which is why `@onclick-...` triggers a render event, and your action, which is not a UI event, doesn't.

Note the calls to `StateHasChanged`.

For reference you can implement this to only make one call:

```
@implements IHandleEvent

//...
@code {
    public async Task HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        await callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Or even this to make only manual calls:

```cs
@implements IHandleEvent

//...
@code {
    public async Task HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
        => callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
}
```