# Blazor Func Property to return calculated value

Tags: c#, blazor, func

Expanding on a prior [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74288671/eventcallback-vs-action), I am having difficulty getting it to work.

To start with the part that Does work, I have a property on a class that happens upon click of a button.

```
public Func<Task> SelectAction { get; set; }
```

The razor portion looks like the following (this is all in an effort to remove lambdas which are expensive and slow the page down.)

```
<div class="cv-selectable" @onclick="row.SelectAction">
```

The `SelectAction` is setup like the following:

```
newClaim.SelectAction = () => SwapClaimSelectedState(newClaim);
```

The `SwapClaimSelectedState` essentially changes an internal properties value. This works great. Here is the full code (question to follow.)

The razor page:

```
@foreach (var row in VisibleDestinations)
{
  if (row.RowType == VirtualCopyRowTypes.Claim)
  {
    <div class="cv-row cv-claim">
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" @onclick="row.ExpandAction">
          <Icon Name="@row.ExpandStateIcon" height="15" />
        </button>
        <div class="cv-selectable" @onclick="row.SelectAction">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
            <Icon Name="@row.DetermineClaimsIconState" height="15" />
          </button>
          <span>@row.ClaimDisplay</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

The `VisibleDestinations` "row" properties in question:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public Func<Task> SelectAction { get; set; }

[JsonIgnore]
public Func<Task> ExpandAction { get; set; }

[JsonIgnore]
public Func<Task> DetermineClaimsIconState { get; set; }
```

The loop to setup the `VisibleDestinations`:

```
foreach (var claim in AllPerformanceClaimsWithVisgrades)
{
  var newClaim = new VirtualCopyRow
  {
    PerformanceClaimId = claim.PerformanceClaimId,
    RowType = VirtualCopyRowTypes.Claim,
    IsVisible = true,
    ClaimDisplay = $"{claim.Issuer} {claim.Name} {claim.Version}",
  };

  newClaim.ExpandAction = () => SwapCollapsedState(newClaim);
  newClaim.SelectAction = () => SwapClaimSelectedState(newClaim);
  newClaim.DetermineClaimsIconState = () => ClaimSelectedStateIcon(newClaim);
  ...
}
```

The method that I want to call within the razor syntax essentially returns 1 of 4 possible icon states based on child object selection states. Think none-selected, some-selected and all-selected:

```
public async Task ClaimSelectedStateIcon(VirtualCopyRow row)
{
  var result = IconNames.Blank;
  var totalChildVisgrades = Destinations
    .Count(x =>
      x.PerformanceClaimId == row.PerformanceClaimId &&
      x.RowType == VirtualCopyRowTypes.Visgrade
    );
  var totalSelectedVisgrades = Destinations
    .Count(x =>
      x.PerformanceClaimId == row.PerformanceClaimId &&
      x.RowType == VirtualCopyRowTypes.Visgrade &&
      x.IsSelected == true
    );

  if (totalChildVisgrades == 0)
    result = IconNames.Blank; // There are no Visgrades on this Claim
  else if (totalSelectedVisgrades == 0)
    result = IconNames.UnselectAll; // There is at least one Visgrade on the Claim and None are selected
  else if (totalChildVisgrades == totalSelectedVisgrades)
    result = IconNames.SelectAll; // There is at least one Visgrade on the Claim and they are All selected
  else
    result = IconNames.SomeSelected; // There is at least two Visgrades on the Claim and at least one but not All are selected

  return result;
}
```

**Question**

I have tried multiple permutations of how to define the `DetermineClaimsIconState` property where I have an `in` and/or `TValue` of `IconNames` and there is always some issue either in code or razor.

I do NOT need this to be a `Func` if some other type will work. The main requirement is that the code-behind needs to be something similar to:

```
newClaim.DetermineClaimsIconState = () => ClaimSelectedStateIcon(newClaim);
```

Where I pass the `newClaim` object to the `ClaimSelectiedStateIcon` method.

AND that the razor code is NOT a lambda so it should look similar to:

```
<Icon Name="@row.DetermineClaimsIconState" height="15" />
```

**UPDATE**

After attempting to implement @MrC-aka-shaun-curtis updates, the c# is good but the razor gives the following error.

[image: Razor error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mrc-aka-shaun-curtis for assistance. The final product is:

```
public Func<VirtualizedRow, IconNames> GetBulkCopyIconState { get; set; }
public IconNames BulkIconStateForRow
{
  get
  {
    var result = IconNames.Blank;

    if (GetBulkCopyIconState is not null)
      result = GetBulkCopyIconState.Invoke(this);

    return result;
  }
}
```

When creating differet rows, they all are setup like the following:

```
visgradeRow.GetBulkCopyIconState = (e) => DetermineBulkCopyIconState(visgradeRow);
```

Do the actual calculation for determining which icon to show:

```
public IconNames DetermineBulkCopyIconState(VirtualizedRow row)
{
  ... Magic sauce

  return result;
}
```

Using it on the razor page/component:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link p-0 bulk-copy" @onclick="cell.SecondaryAction">
  <Icon Name="@row.BulkIconStateForRow" height="12" class="@row.BulkIconStateForRow" />
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your method `ClaimSelectedStateIcon`:

1. The return type is `Task`, but you try to return an `IconValues` object [I assume an enum?].
2. I see no async methods called so I assume you're getting warnings about that.

It should look like:

```cs
public  Task<IconNames> ClaimSelectedStateIcon(VirtualCopyRow row)
{
  var result = IconNames.Blank;

    //....

  return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

And your delegate declared:

```cs
public Func<Task<IconNames>> DetermineClaimsIconState { get; set; }
```

Comment: thank you. Yes, IconValues is an enum. Yes, `ClaimSelectedStateIcon` does warn with no `await`. I altered the property as you suggested. The C# compiles no issue. The razor though, gives me the following error - well, see UPDATE above in my OP for image.

Comment: That's because `Icon` expects an `IconNames` type.  Is the `Icon` component yours or one from a library?

Comment: Why don't you calculate the `IconNames` whwn you create the `VirtualCopyRow`?

Comment: Note that `x =>  x.PerformanceClaimId == row.PerformanceClaimId &&
      x.RowType == VirtualCopyRowTypes.Visgrade` is an anonymous function which is created every time you call it!

Comment: Yes, Icon is our own component. It simply servers up an svg based on the enum IconNames. The IconName cannot be caluculated when the VirtualCopyRow is created because there are checkboxes that can be toggled on and off for each of the rows. The icon I am attempting to show is a tri-state of None selected, Some selected and All selected. Thus, when a lower checkbox is checked or unchecked, I need to recalculate the parents icon state. Like a treeview similar to this: https://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/SimpleTriStateTreeView/TriStateTreeView.png